# How to sort a list of strings based off the capitalized letter within that list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Ive been working on this question for quite some time. For example, when given

C b a

c B a

c b A

I would like to produce

c  b  A

c  B a

a b C

so that the capatalized words are now in alphabetical order. Anything helps!

Comment: What if there are two or more capitalised letter in your string?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* result of how you spent "quite some time" on this?

Comment: why downvotes? is a good question

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what the sort is here. Please clarify. 
It would also be helpful to list what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = ['C b a', 'c B a', 'c b A']
new_s = sorted(s, key=lambda x:re.findall('[A-Z]+', x)[0])
```

Output:

```
['c b A', 'c B a', 'C b a']
```